# A toroidal graph to identify (with illustration)

Tags: graph-theory

I posted this before, was asked for a diagram because I only had a confused prose description, and by the time I added the diagram I believe the thread had long disappeared from the first few pages people are likely to be browsing. If a repost is not appropriate please let me know and I will remove it.

The graph I would like to identify has 24 vertices, 144 edges and diameter 2; it is a toroidally wrapped portion of a hexagonal grid where all interior diagonals of each hexagon are also edges of the graph. It is highly symmetrical; if mirror reflection is allowed then any vertex can be mapped into any other. The attached image illustrates: the yellow circles are the nodes of the graph, and the colored edges indicate how the repeating portion of the grid wraps around on itself.

I haven't mastered systems of graph nomenclature. If someone could identify the graph, I'm hoping I will be able to use that information to find out more information about it.

Thanks![image: graph illustration]

Comment: If you edit the original to include the diagram, it will bumped to the first page. (Not that I care about the repost, just saying).

Comment: I've counted and counted, and I see 25 vertices, not 24. There are 12 that are interior to the red-blue-green border, and 13 on the border: 6 that touch two green edges, 4 that touch two red edges, 2 on the blue edge, and 1 at the place that the red and green edges come together.

Comment: MJD: the ones around the boundary end up getting reused. If I go around clockwise from the highest point (i.e. where blue meets green), labelling that point "1", I get 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8. Vertices 1 and 8 appear three times each. I think I've drawn it correctly, let me know if it still looks wrong.